# ios Adding SubView to a ScrollView not on center

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I have an iOS project that adds a subview to a nib. The subview's contents are set to the center using autolayout, but when the subview is added to the scrollview, the subview's contents are not on center.
Here is the code:

```
UIView *scroller = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"scroller" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
[self.view addSubview:scroller];

CGSize size = self.view.bounds.size;
NSLog(@"view size: %f", size.width);
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(size.width, size.height);
self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
self.myView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
self.scrollView.bounds = self.myView.bounds;
[self.scrollView addSubview:self.myView];
```

Also here is what the output looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RxYh.jpg

I have also uploaded my project:
http://www.filedropper.com/myproject

Comment: Where is the auto-layout spec? What is `self.myView`? Why are you setting the scroll view `bounds`? How does this relate to `scroller`?

Comment: Whats the reason for `self.scrollView.bounds = self.myView.bounds;` ?

Comment: self.myView is the view that I am trying to display inside of the scrollview. It is loaded in the nib called "scroller." I set the scroll view bounds because I thought it would fix my problems. If i don't the bounds, the view is still loaded off center.

Comment: there are 2 views inside of scroller. one is just a view with a scroll view in it. the other is a view with an image, label, and textfield

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Here's the code I used:

```
UIView *scroller = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"scroller" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
[self.view addSubview:scroller];

CGSize size = self.view.bounds.size;
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(size.width, size.height+200);
self.myView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
[self.scrollView addSubview:self.myView];
```